# condition of agent type in SelectOutPut (AnyLogic)

Tags: java, queue, anylogic

I am working on AnyLogic. 
Suppose I have 3 agent types (Male, Female and Cats) (the screenshot in the link).

The question: I want the Male and the Female to go "only" to "MandF Queue" and the Cats to go to "only" to "C queue" after the selectOutput.

I tried to put an If-Statement in the "probability" bar in selectOutput, but I didn`t know how to extract the name of the agent. Should I use a parameter? like what if I have for instance 12 agent types, what is the way?[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUpkI.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:
in the selectouput, in the select true output option of the configuration choose "if condition is true"

and in the condition use this:

```
agent instanceof Male || agent instanceof Female
```

Comment: what if there are more than 2 genders + I only named them as male and female, how anylogic can know whether the entered agent is male or female ?

Comment: what??? I answered exactly that... I dont undersatnd your issue now

Comment: I tried the above solution in my simulation where I have only two agent types. "Applicant" and "Priority Applicant". I typed as 'agent InstanceOf Applicant'. But I got a few errors such as "Cannot convert Agent to Boolean", "insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression.". Have I done anything wrong? @Felipe